# Configure HTTPS Cloned Project via GIT to pull without GIT Password

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I cloned my project via `https` into my VM about 3 weeks ago.

The main goal is to avoid having to type the password every time, I need to pull.
Now, I created an SSH key, copy my `id_rda.pub` and add that to my BitBucket Access Keys.

I pulled I kept getting prompted for GIT password.

How do I configure GIT so I don't have to reclone via SSH?

Comment: Did you give the ssh key a password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `git remote -v` still shows HTTPS URLs, then you'll need to update it:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git
```

Comment: Works on the first try !!